# question from russian math olympiad

Tags: contest-math

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x+y-1)(x+y-2)$ be a function of two positive integers. 
Prove that for any positive integer $z$ there exists a single pair $x,y$ such that
$f(x,y)=z$.

Isn't this clearly wrong? E.g. for $z=5$, there can be no successive pairs of integers $a,a'$ such that $\frac{1}{2}aa'=5$?

Comment: Seems kinda easy for a olympiad question,from where did you get this problem?

Comment: @kingW3 How easy? The question is wrong. It's from 1988.

Comment: Even if it was right,they don't give that type of questions.If it was written right it would still seem pretty easy.Anyway where did you get this problem?
EDIT:Maybe there is minus or plus sign somewhere not intended

Comment: @kingW3 It's from here http://andrej.fizika.org/ostalo/gimnazija/math/ruske_olimpijade/11a-olym-1.pdf, 1988, 51.9.4

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the question as stated is incorrect.

Comment: It's from 1988. Maybe it has been wrongly translated.

Answer (score -1):

From question we can form the equation 
$$z = 1/2(x+y-2)(x+y-1)$$

let $x+y = a$

$$2z = (a - 2)(a - 1)$$
$$2z = a^2 -3a + 2$$
$$a^2 -3a -2(z - 1)=0$$
apply
$b^2 - 4ac$;
 $9+8(z-1)$

Now the discriminant have to be greater than or equal to $0$.

Let $z = 1$ the smallest positive integer.
Since
$9>0$
then any positive integer value for $z$ will satisfy
and the $x +y$ can be found;
hence proved;